# MAVEN: No plugin found for prefix 'dependency' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]

Tags: maven-2

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'dependency' in the current project
>   and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
>   available from the repositories [local
>   (C:\Users\mdhore.m2\repository), central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>3.0.2</version> 
    <executions> 
      <execution> 
        <id>copy-dependencies</id> 
        <phase>package</phase> 
        <goals> 
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal> 
        </goals> 
        <configuration> 
          <!-- configure the plugin here --> 
        </configuration> 
      </execution> 
    </executions> 
  </plugin> 
</plugins>
```

Comment: it may be an issue with java10, see https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript/issues/122

Comment: Did you find a solution or workaround for this?

Comment: @HolgerBrandl I don't think it's Java 10, it's happening to me with 1.8.0_171 and Maven 3.5.4.

Comment: And never mind, it would have happened to me with any version of anything because I fat-fingered it and misspelled "dependency" :/

Comment: oops, I misspelled `dependency` as well ;) Make sure to check your `mvn` command again.

Answer (score 20):

according to [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException) you have to provide group and artifact id. I run `mvn dependencies:tree` like the following and it worked.

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree -Dverbose=true
```

Comment: Actually, this is a correct answer and should be marked accordingly. It seems that @sonu made a typo in his command line execution like (incorrect plugin artifactId):
> mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:dependency-plugin:2.10:tree
It is better to execute a shortened command:
> mvn dependency:tree

Answer (score 2):

I have also encountered the same issue. I typed the wrong command `mvn dependences:resolve`, the correct one is `mvn dependency:resolve`.

Answer (score 1):

This should not have happen for usual plugins.
E.g. for [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/index.html), there is no need to run it as
`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile`

So most likely, you have made a **typo** mistake in command line.

[image]

---

But if you have some other plugin not from [maven land](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html)

then add a line into `~/.m2/settings.xml`

e.g. for `dependency-check-maven` plugin https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/

I added `<pluginGroup>org.owasp</pluginGroup>`

```xml
  <pluginGroups>
    <!-- pluginGroup
     | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.
    <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
    -->
    <pluginGroup>org.owasp</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
```

So now just `mvn dependency-check:check` works.

---

P.S. I have just tried `mvn maven-compiler-plugin:compile` and it failed

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'maven-compiler-plugin' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.owasp, org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/pverest/.m2/repository), nexus (https://nexus.**********/repository/maven-public/)]

`mvn compiler:compile` works

`mvn dependency:help` works

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I forgot to add this parameter. I have to add to each of my Maven comamnds to autheticate with my Maven remote repository.
`-Djava.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts.jks`. If you don't normally add a parameter like this you probably have another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and in my case I didn't have the POM file in the same directory I was in.

Answer (score 0):

An authentication problem (if your repo requires it) can lead to the same problem. Watch out for a Warning (strangely) that says something like

```
Authentication failed for **** ...
401 Unauthorized
```

The plugin metadata could not be retrieved:

```
Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml
```

so I ended up with the error described in the question.

I had to update the authentication credentials `NEXUS_USER` and `NEXUS_PASS` (because someone else changed the password without telling).

Answer (score -3):

make sure there is no import error anywhere in your code then run `mvn dependency:tree` the error will be gone. I assume you are using mvn and you have some import issue somewhere in your project.

Comment: import issue for sure are not related